# Is it possible to rename the db host name?

Tags: ddev

I've got an odd use case where I'm adding DDEV to a project, but for reasons I'd like the db host to be 'mysql' instead of 'db'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `.ddev/docker-compose.hostname.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    hostname: mysql
```